# Custom Socket Factory

Tags: android, sockets

I want to create a custom Socket Factory which can catch network traffic (i want to get all incoming and outgoing headers especially).
I have tried reading java reflection api and also looked at **android.webkit.Network** class for android version less than 14 and **android.webkit.WebViewCore** for versions greater than 14 but could not find solution or any logic.
If anybody can give me code sample for that then it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Did you google ? http://blog.callistaenterprise.se/2011/11/24/android-tlsssl-mutual-authentication/

Comment: @KumarGaurav.. Yes i had mentioned. The link that you had sent me is similar to many links that i got from google.. no use

Comment: You need to give a push. I mean "A Start".

Comment: @KumarGaurav..i applied many approaches but all in vain... thats why i asked here atlast :)